# Using ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET, how can I display the legend or symbology of an image, along with the image, on a map?

Tags: raster, c#, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

Using ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET, how can I display the legend or symbology of an image, along with the image, on a map?
I have an ArcGIS runtime program written in C#, which generates a series of rasters, and displays them on a map using the following code snippit . . .

```
private void AddRasterLayer(string rasterPath, string id, bool isVisible, double[,] rasterArray)
{
    var newRaster = new Raster(rasterPath);             //  create the raster object from the image file
    var newRasterLayer = new RasterLayer(newRaster);    //  create the raster layer object from the raster
    newRasterLayer.Id = id;
    if (id == "DEMMosaic")// if the image is the DEM
    {
        double max = SoilMoisturePreprocessing.Max2d(rasterArray);  // get the maximum value in the array
        double min = SoilMoisturePreprocessing.Min2d(rasterArray);  // get the minimum value in the array
        double[] minVals = { min }; // minimum value for stretch parameters input
        double[] maxVals = { max }; // maximum value for stretch parameters input
        MinMaxStretchParameters minMaxParams = new MinMaxStretchParameters(minVals, maxVals);   // create stretch parameters object
        ColorRamp elevationColorRamp = ColorRamp.Create(PresetColorRampType.Elevation); // create the color ramp

        var rendrr = new StretchRenderer(minMaxParams, null, true, elevationColorRamp); // create the renderer from the above
        newRasterLayer.Renderer = rendrr;   // apply the renderer to the raster layer
    }

    newRasterLayer.Opacity = 0.6;           // set the opacity
    newRasterLayer.IsVisible = isVisible;   // visibility setting

    var mapViewModel = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MapViewModel>();  // get the map view model
    mapViewModel.Map.OperationalLayers.Add(newRasterLayer);                 // add the raster layer to the map 

}
```

Is there a way that I could incorporate into the above code, a method that would display a legend for the raster along with the raster?